# How to protect sensitive data in URL's

Tags: php

So i am trying to protect some data in an URL, so it can not be manipulated.

I found this site:

```
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_protect_sensitive_data_in_URL's
```

I followed the steps of this site. The site says

```
The above will give you a value like "\xd8\x75\x26\xd5\x59\x45\x47\x1b\x02\x13\x13\xa5\xa8\x4d\x61\xd8\x94\xb0\x87\x60\x40\x2f\x29\x63\x2f\x13\x9c\xc3\x42\x88\xf1\xe5".
 * Use that for $secret instead of a human-readable password.
```

I did all this and got such a random key generated, then i used the key instead of of an human-redable password like mentioned above. The problem is, when i give this random generated key to the next site, how will this site be able to generated the same key and then tell me if they are equal or not? I hope it's understandable enough... If i generate something randomly on page1, how can page2 know how exactly the random generated key has to look like? I can only generate another key on Page2 but it will never be the same like page1.

Comment: Dont ever send passwords in a URL.

Comment: In my case it's not a password, it's just a customer_id, but anyway i don't want it to be manipulated. And if you would have read the link, you would have known that the $secret key is not the data i try to send, it's just some security thing.

Comment: Use sessions instead, to check. even encoded data can be manipulated

Comment: Either use `sessions` or encrypt the data. Though this might be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1):

What I have used in the past is the following approach:

Having the following set of data:

```
$array = Array(
  'TIMESTAMP' => time(),
  'USERID' => 'idhere'
)
```

I would first serialize this array to get a representation of it's value, and then Encode this information with MIME base64:

```
?param-in-url=base64_encode(serialize($array));
```

Later on you can receive it back using:

```
$data = unserialize( base64_decode( $_REQUEST['param-in-url'] ) );
```

Comment: Well in fact this works, but on the other side the question is, how safe is this?

Comment: Sure not un-breakable. I would make a compromise between security/method to transfer data, since passing data in url is sth inherently unsafe.

Comment: So thanks for your anwer, i will think about this but maybe i will go with the way to store everything i need in session.